# Python Import a module which it itself import another file

Tags: python, import

I have a python file named x.py which imports another file named y.py. y.py itself imports z.py, y.py and z.py are in the same directory but x.py is in the parent directory. 
When I use relative import in y.py e.g. `import .z` y does not work and x works. When I change import to `import z` y.py works but x.py does not work

```
dic1  
    |__x.py
    |__dic2
         |__y.py
         |__z.py

x imports y
y imports z
```

is there any solution to import a python file that imports another file in different directories.

Comment: Add an empty file named `__init__.py` in every folder and then try again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Blueteeth and Sofian for your responses. Apology for my incomplete question and I think I could not tell the exact point.

Finally, I used
`import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "dic2")`

in y.py

Answer (score 3):

Packages in Python need to have an `__init__.py` file at the root of them. Here I'm a bit confused as to what is a package and what is the root directory.

I would have something like this:

```
<root_directory>
  |__ setup.py
  |__ <other top level files>
  |__ dic1/
    |__ __init__.py
    |__ x.py
    |__ dic2/
      |__ y.py
      |__ z.py
```

You've tagged this as `python`, so I don't know if you're using Python2 or Python3. Given the former is end of life, you should really be using Python3.

You can import things relative to the root **package**, in this example, `dic1`.

If using python2, you need `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of every file.

**x.py**

```
from dic1.dic2 import y
```

**y.py**

```
from dic1.dic2 import z
```

Comment: I just finished my answer and right then I saw that you already wrote the same -.- (upvoted)

Comment: For me the following worked, in x.py -> 
from dic2 import y, 

and in y.py -> 
from dic2 import z. 

However, I reached here only because of your answer. Thanks